# Next.js not generating a project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I am trying to build a project and in the tutorial they tell me to start with this

npx create-next-app --e with-tailwindcss amazon-scraper

But when it completes building I only have a readme.md and a gitignore folder.

Even though I am a beginner I already worked with npx create-next app and it worked alright.

It is really frustating since I am trying to start a new project and I am stuck right at the beginning. Thanks for your help.

[This is what I should get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRVcB.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.